# KnockoutJS Select item from foreach

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a foreach binding

```
<table id="Table_OperationsGroup">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: groupOperationsGroup">
        <!-- ko if: $index() < $root.groupOperationsGroup().length - 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="changeGroup: groupOperations,options: operators, optionsText: 'Name', value: groupOperations" style="width: 105px;margin-top:5px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-left:0px !important;"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.changeGroup = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //some code to work with the select
    }
};


var groupOperationsTemplate = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.groupOperations = ko.observable(operators);
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([{
        operations: ko.observable()
    }]);
    self.addLine = function (line) {
        line.lines.push({
            operations: ko.observable(operators)
        })
    };
    self.removeLine = function (line) {
        if (self.lines().length > 1) {
            self.lines.remove(line);
        }
    };
};

var Filter = function () {
    var self = this;
    //self.template = ko.observableArray();    
    self.groupOperationsGroup = ko.observableArray([new groupOperationsTemplate()]);
    self.addGroupOperator = function (data) {
        self.groupOperationsGroup.splice(self.groupOperationsGroup.indexOf(data) + 1, 0, new groupOperationsTemplate());
    };
};

var vm = new Filter();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

So, what I want is, if someone change the select, I want to pick up exactly the select which is changing in the bindinghandler. The problem is, that the bindinghandler is called for every select. It Begins at 0 and then 1,2,3 and so on.
I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: binding handler will be called every insert to binded list. so basically if you subscribe groupOperations will your code act as you liked it ?

Comment: You are right. If i create a subscriber it works as expected. But i have choose the bindinghandler, so that i have access to bindingContext, $root, ... . Can i do this with a subscriber??

Comment: I somehow didnt understand code. you are using value =>groupOperations and  options => operators. But groupOperations also uses operators. Dont you think this is kind of weird ?  If you need this functinotality many places binding handler would do good. but it seems you dont need it. if groupOperations were simple observable value you would subscribe it.

Comment: operators is just an object var operators = [
    {
        "Name": "Und",
        "Wert": 0
    },
    {
        "Name": "Und nicht",
        "Wert": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "Oder",
        "Wert": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Oder nicht",
        "Wert": 3
  }
]; is it not neccassary to set value??

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html. I have used the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets discuss here.

operators is an array ,  and you use it to bind select

> self.groupOperations = ko.observable(operators);

instead of

```
self.groupOperations = ko.observableArray([ { "Name": "Und", "Wert": 0 }, { "Name": "Und nicht", "Wert": 1 }, { "Name": "Oder", "Wert": 2 }, { "Name": "Oder nicht", "Wert": 3 } ]);
self.selectedValue = ko.observable();

self.selectedValue.subscribe(function( newValue) {
   //do whatever you want with new value
});
```

when binding to select

```
 <!-- ko if: $index() < $root.groupOperationsGroup().length - 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: groupOperations, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedValue" style="width: 105px;margin-top:5px !important;margin-bottom:5px !important;margin-left:0px !important;"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thats right. I use operators for several bindings. And with every push  i create i new groupOperationsTemplate with a new select and a new groupOperations. The function is addGreoupOperator. So why the subscriber is worked as expected and the bindinghandler not?? i don't understand the difference.

Comment: I would like to show you a picture of what i mean, but i can't.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle  for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lrz_hal/cTR6v/26/. If you click on "Filter hinzufügen" you can add a new line inside the groupoperationsTemplate. If you click on "Filtergruppe hinzufügen" you put a new groupOperationsTemplate. So what i want is, if you have multiple lines of groupOperationsTemplate, i want to detect wich select on the left has changed, and then loop through all the other selects and change them. The Project is an ldap Filter. And in ldap you only can have "und" and "und nicht" together. Or "Oder" and "Oder nicht".

Comment: this look too complicated can i do it without bindingHandler and one combobox ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cTR6v/34/ I think you dont need binding handler for this kind of business. because you wont going to use this every page and your binding handler is dependent on data/object. A good binding handler would be : render each number value in textbox with two presicion. ko.bindinghandler.twoPrecision . In this case instead of using binding handler you can use subscribe etc. would this be ok for you ? Why do you have to use binding handler.

Comment: Because with binding handler i have acces to the viewmodelobject and so i cand find out which select was changed (`bindingContext.$root.groupOperationsGroup.indexOf(viewModel)`). if i use subscribe i only can read out the values and have no access to the viewmodel object

Comment: but you are in the viewmodel you can access groupOperationsGroup in subscribe method ? just pass parent object to it. you are done. sorry for late answer

Comment: Hi adt. I now got it working. Here is the working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/lrz_hal/cTR6v/38/ Thank you for the explanation about handlers and subscriptions.

Comment: i am glad it is working. but please refactor these if statements to minimize them and you may consider accepting answers, higher accept ratio will help you to get more help in here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I will note your tips in the future!!